# How can I let Watson Assistant play on hold music?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am building an conversational IVR by Watson Assistant. How can I let it play on hold music? or on hold text-to-speech?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of a chatbot is to get away from "dead space" and Musak.  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your response. I guess you are right about it. I wanted it because I thought there might be cases that the bot needs time to look for information.